# iOS Action Extension share from GarageBand

Tags: ios, swift, audio, react-native, ios-app-extension

I am building an action extension for GarageBand on iOS which transforms and uploads audio but no matter what I try, I just could not get to the exported file.

Let’s consider the following code — it should:

1. find and load shared audio from `extensionContext`
2. initialise audio player
3. play the sound

It works if I run the extension in Voice Memos.app — the url to the file looks like this: `file:///tmp/com.apple.VoiceMemos/New%20Recording%202.m4a`

Now, If I run the code in GarageBand.app, the url points to (what I presume) is GarageBand’s app container, as the url looks something like `/var/…/Containers/…/Project.band/audio/Project.m4a`, and the audio will not be loaded and cannot therefore be manipulated in any way.

// edit: If I try to load contents of the audio file, it looks like the data only contains aac header (?) but the rest of the file is empty

What is interesting is this: The extension renders a `react-native` view and if I pass the view the fileUrl (`/var/…Project.band/audio/Project.m4a`) and then pass it down to `XMLHTTPRequest`, the file gets uploaded. So it looks like the file can be accessed in some way?

I’m new to Swift/iOS development so this is kind of frustrating for me, I feel like I tried just about everything.

### The code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var audioFound :Bool = false
    for inputItem: Any in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
        let extensionItem = inputItem as! NSExtensionItem
        for attachment: Any in extensionItem.attachments! {
            print("attachment = \(attachment)")
            let itemProvider = attachment as! NSItemProvider
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeAudio as String) {
                itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeAudio as String,
                                                       options: nil, completionHandler: { (audioURL, error) in
                                                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                                                            if let audioURL = audioURL as? NSURL {
                                                                print("audioUrl = \(audioURL)")

                                                                // in our sample code we just present and play the audio in our app extension
                                                                let theAVPlayer :AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: audioURL as URL)
                                                                let theAVPlayerViewController :AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                                                                theAVPlayerViewController.player = theAVPlayer
                                                                self.present(theAVPlayerViewController, animated: true) {
                                                                    theAVPlayerViewController.player!.play()
                                                                }

                                                            }
                                                        }
                })

                audioFound = true
                break
            }
        }

        if (audioFound) {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution/workaround for this problem? I'm in the same boat...

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but unfortunately not :( This was was just a proof-of-concept project and I haven’t found the time to finish it. I’ll update the question if I ever find a solution.